# MUI Datatable - How to style rows when using aggregates

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Currently using custom styled rows/columns, will also style the aggregate column. How can I style this row without effecting the aggregate row?

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-euler-1szk2y?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the renderCell: =

```
  {
        field: SomeFieldName,
        headerName: SomeHeaderName,
        type: number,
        width: 140,
        renderCell: renderCellFunction,
}




export const renderCellFunction = (params: GridRenderCellParams<Partial<RowDataType>, any, any, GridTreeNodeWithRender>) => {
    if (params.aggregation) {
        return <Typography color="primary.main">{params.formattedValue}</Typography>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Typography>{params.row.xyz}</Typography>
        </div>
    );
};
```